# How do I fix this error with packaging python scripts

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So i'm packaging a python script with pyinstaller, and when I run the executable that is output in the dist folder, i see this error:
https://gyazo.com/729db46f4e7973b475b11c5a9810da19

Here is a screenshot of the error since the video goes fast:
https://gyazo.com/6f39ffd35561c3bc976aa9e52ee363f4

The line that the error refers to is this:

```
title = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Discord Tools")
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you run your code without exception before you use pyinstaller?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Yep